# Android cropper library slows with big images

Tags: android

I use library cropper [here](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper/wiki#Contributions)

All work cool. But if i use big image it work slows

```
com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView 

    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/imageCrop"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout5"/>


    crudeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
```

how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean it works slow?

Comment: slows when I overtighten area that trims